# Pandas dataframe randomly shuffle consecutive rows of values based on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, permutation, shuffle

I would also like to groupby a certain column and then shuffle n consecutive rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'grouper_col':[1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2], 'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6,21,22,23,24,25,26]})

    grouper_col   b
0             1   1
1             1   2
2             1   3
3             1   4
4             1   5
5             1   6
6             2  21
7             2  22
8             2  23
9             2  24
10            2  25
11            2  26
```

and then shuffle for example two consecutive rows within each group, giving for example:

```
    grouper_col   b
0             1   5
1             1   6
2             1   3
3             1   4
4             1   1
5             1   2
6             2  21
7             2  22
8             2  25
9             2  26
10            2  23
11            2  24
```

where two consecutive rows per group are randomly shuffled with two other consecutive rows in the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to approach this:

```
# find the size of each group
sizes = df.groupby('grouper_col').b.size()
# iterate over the elements of the above series
for g, v in sizes.items():
    v -= 1
    # only randomly shuffle if there are more than 4
    if v > 4:
        random_s = np.array([0,0])
        while abs(random_s[0] - random_s[1]) <= 1:
            # if the indices are next to each other not valid
            random_s = np.random.randint(0, v, 2)
        # add 1 to the above indices (i.e [0,2] to [[0,1][2,3]])
        replace_ix = random_s[:,None] + np.array([0,1])
        # keep indices to replace and replace
        to_replace = df.loc[df.grouper_col.eq(g), 'b'].values
        repl_1 = to_replace[replace_ix[0]]
        repl_2 = to_replace[replace_ix[1]]
        to_replace[replace_ix[0]] = repl_2
        to_replace[replace_ix[1]] = repl_1
        df.loc[df.grouper_col.eq(g), 'b'] = to_replace
```

---

```
print(df)

    grouper_col   b
0             1   5
1             1   6
2             1   3
3             1   4
4             1   1
5             1   2
6             2  21
7             2  25
8             2  26
9             2  24
10            2  22
11            2  23
```

Comment: This was quick, thanks a lot - however, I get the following error: NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Thanks a lot. How would you generalize it if you have more than 2 consecutive rows to shuffle? I tried to replace random_s but this did not work.